# Trouble with php mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, handler

i'm having some mod_rewrite problems. I am working on a rewrite simple rewrite tool that should help me with my website. but i don't know where is the problem

this is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^text\/$ text.php [L,NC]
```

and my `phpinfo()` says that i have my mod_rewrite loaded

also i have a `apache hadler: AllowOverride On`

so I don't know why this isn't working... can anyone tell me what else could be the problem ?

Comment: Is everything in your .htaccess in one line like that, or is each command on it's own line?

Comment: there are three lines in my .htaccess...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Note that you do not need to escape the forward slash.

Comment: if i open text.php in my browser I should see this URL: domain.com/text... right ? the problem is that nothing happens... URL is still domain.com/text.php... and also if i type domain.com/text into the URL i get a error 404.. so rewrite simply dosen't work... and i don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following at the top of your .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Also, what rewrites do is allow you to go to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/text
```

and see the content that would be generated if you actually went to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/text.php
```

rather than the other way around. So the rewrite rules are basically

```
RewriteRule <what-I-type-in-my-address-bar> <what-page-I-see>
```

Comment: still the same problem :( 404 :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the escape slash in the rewrite rule to be `text/$` and navigating to `mydomain.com/text/`?